# Invariance of a maximally entangled state under unitary operation $U \otimes U^\dagger$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Apparently the (d-dimensional) maximally entangled state, $|E \rangle = \sum_{i} |ii\rangle /\sqrt{d}$ is invariant under operations of the form $U \otimes U^\dagger$. I want to prove this result, which amounts to showing that

$$\left(\sum_i U | i \rangle \otimes V |i \rangle = \sum_i | ii \rangle \right)\Rightarrow (V = U^\dagger )$$

I have no idea how to even start. I suppose it's some simple linear algebra result, but I don't see it. A hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the terms $U |i \rangle$ and $V | i \rangle$ explicitly in the matrix form, e.g., $U | i \rangle = \sum_{k}  | k \rangle U_{ki}$ and analogously. Then play with exchanging the three summations of indices, you should get it proved.

Answer (score 4):

One reason you might have trouble proving that is that **it isn't true**. For example, apply $\sqrt Y \otimes \sqrt Y^\dagger$ where $\sqrt{Y} = \frac{1+i}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ to the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left( |00\rangle + |11\rangle \right)$ and you get the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \left(|01\rangle - |10\rangle \right)$.

[In Quirk](http://algorithmicassertions.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Density2%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22Y%5E%C2%BD%22%2C%22Y%5E-%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B%22Density2%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%5D%7D):

[image: Quirk circuit]

---

**I think that you're supposed to be applying $U \otimes U^*$ instead of $U \otimes U^\dagger$**; the conjugate instead of the conjugate transpose.

The reason I think that is because I know that [entangled states act like unitary matrices](http://algorithmicassertions.com/quantum/2015/04/25/Entangled-States-are-like-Unitary-Matrices.html). If you lay the amplitudes of Alice and Bob's fully entangled qubits out in a grid $M$ then any operation $A$ that Alice applies will correspond to pre-multiplying $M$ by $A$ while any operation $B$ that Bob applies will correspond to post-multiplying $M$ by the transpose $B^T$. When they each apply an operation and $B=A^*$ that means together they did $M \rightarrow A M (A^*)^T$. The fully entangled state you described is where $M=I$ so $A M (A^*)^T = A I A^\dagger = A A^\dagger = I$.